# What are the current legal issues going on between Ubuntu and Microsoft?

Tags: canonical, microsoft

I know this is none of my business, still, since Microsoft always tries to bump its competitors, i was wondering what current legal issues are  going on between Ubuntu and Microsoft Corp., and is there anyway common ubuzens like me can help in those matters?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/88366/what-is-the-legal-status-of-libraries-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any legal issues between Ubuntu and Microsoft. Indeed, Microsoft is contributing to the development of several key technologies we use in Ubuntu -- most notably Linux and Samba4. They're not the same bad guy they used to be. There are other companies I would be more afraid of, with Apple being the primary bully.

Comment: If we're in the subject... does buying some stuff from Ubuntu Shop helps its development, or these items are just a cool stuff?